# Linux command to copy a file to a remote server

Tags: linux

I have no Linux experience, all I know and want to do is this:

There is a JAR file on my local computer that I want to copy to a remote box.
I think it is a Linux box, and I do a ssh to connect to it like this:

```
ssh myUserName@boxName
```

and then I enter my password and I connect to it.

Now I just want to copy a local file from my machine to that remote box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the ssh enabled boxes have sftp enabled.

You can try to sftp to the box using

> sftp myUserName@boxName
>
> put filename

Comment: sftp worked but "puts" said "invalid command" .. so it is not enabled?

Comment: my bad its 'put' and not 'puts'

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`scp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?scp%201) command:

```
scp file.txt user@remote.host:/path/to/file.txt
```

From the man page:

> scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data
>        transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security
>        as ssh(1).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the 'scp' (secure copy) command to do this:

```
scp file.jar myUserName@boxName:/path/to/destination
```

And, to get it back (to your current directory), just reverse the arguments:

```
scp myUserName@boxName:/path/to/destination/file.jar .
```

If you're wanting to do directories recursively, you can do that with scp by passing the -r switch along with a directory location.  I'd suggest having a look at rsync if you want to do this, however, as it contains some cool optimisations for copying large directories.

Tom.

Answer (score 3):

`scp localfileName myUserName@boxName:remotefileName`

scp is secure copy and runs over ssh.

Check man scp for details

Answer (score 0):

If there is an identity key (RSA) instead of password than `-i` should be added

```
scp -i /path/to/key username@example.com:/remote/path/to/file /local/path
```